# SharePoint Foundation 2010 Time Card - show other user entries

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I was able to create a time card as per this link -- 
http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=105

Is there a way that the admin can see ALL users' time card entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those with Full Control on the list permissions should be able to see all entries (in theory). I haven't used that list template before and she doesn't mention anything about any custom permissions in her article.

There is this comment:
"You guys, if you want to see all time cards, you have to go into the list settings and scroll down to the bottom and create a new view from there.  That should let you see all of them."

Comment: The template is a web part and not list - hence I cannot see the list permissions option

Comment: You need to navigate to the TimeCard list. Click the heading of the Webpart to navigate there.